# Next js 13 app not routing properly using trailingSlash set to true

Tags: next.js, next.js13, trailing-slash

i'm using the latest nexjs 13 version and i set trailingSlash to true. when i try to navigate to http://localhost:3000/blog/efficiently-matching-you-with-trusted-helpers/ i get this instead http://localhost:3000/blog/blog/efficiently-matching-you-with-trusted-helpers/ resulting to a 404 page error but i when i set trailingSlash to false it works properly. The reason i'm using using trialingSlash is because after hosting the static app to cpanel, on hard refresh of any page i get a 404 error and using trailingSlash set to true corrects it but i get the duplicate blog when routing to a slug

i've tried rewriting file permissions in the cpanel but still no positive solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.